# MDX How to group a set

Tags: sum, set, average, mdx

Does anybody have an idea to solve my problem?

I have to compare some values in different periods ( 30.12.2017 – 05.1.2018  /  30.12.2016 – 05.01.2017 / … )
Therefore I defined a mdx with sets per period:

```
WITH 
SET [Period 1]  as  { STRTOMEMBER( "[Created].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2017-12-30T00:00:00]" 
                : STRTOMEMBER( "[Created].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2018-01-04T00:00:00]" )  }

SET [Period 2]  as  { STRTOMEMBER( "[Created].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2016-12-30T00:00:00]" ) 
                : STRTOMEMBER( "[Created].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2017-01-04T00:00:00]" )  }


SELECT 
    NON EMPTY {  [Measures].[Average Price], [Measures].[Average Position]  } ON COLUMNS,

    NON EMPTY (  {   [Period 1], [Period 2] }  ) on rows

FROM [Cube]
```

This works when I want the results per day, but how I can get the values (average/sum) per period? The needed result is to have 2 rows one for Period1 and one for Period2.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just apply an aggregate function to each within the `WITH` clause:

```
WITH 
SET [Period 1]  as  
    STRTOMEMBER( "[Created].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2017-12-30T00:00:00]" 
    : 
    STRTOMEMBER( "[Created].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2018-01-04T00:00:00]" )
SET [Period 2]  as  
    STRTOMEMBER( "[Created].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2016-12-30T00:00:00]" ) 
    : 
    STRTOMEMBER( "[Created].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2017-01-04T00:00:00]" ) 
MEMBER [Created].[Year -  Month -  Date].[All].[Period 1 Agg] AS  
   AGGREGATE( [Period 1]    )   
MEMBER [Created].[Year -  Month -  Date].[All].[Period 2 Agg] AS  
   AGGREGATE( [Period 2]    )    
SELECT 
    NON EMPTY {  [Measures].[Average Price], [Measures].[Average Position]  } ON 0,
    NON EMPTY 
     {  
       [Created].[Year -  Month -  Date].[All].[Period 1 Agg],
       [Created].[Year -  Month -  Date].[All].[Period 2 Agg] 
     }  on 1
FROM [Cube];
```

Comment: thanks, but your proposal show an error: "the measures-hirachy is on the axis-0 allready".

Comment: @Katharina321 apologies I was being lazy - you need to tag each member onto an existing hierarchy - let me edit (you might need to adjust so they use the correct All member in your cube)